# Price filter - override default behaviour to not subtract 0.01 from maximum price

Tags: price, filter, collection-filtering

I have installed the Layered Navigation SEO extension from Catalin (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html) and I have noticed an issue which manifests itself with the price slider functionality of this extension.

Magento's default behaviour with price filtering is to create ranges, and all these ranges, except the uppermost one, have the maximum price set to 0.01 lower than the beginning of the next range.

What this means is that with the aforementioned extension, although you select whole numbers in the slider (and the filter it adds to the URL has these whole numbers), Magento still subtracts 0.01 from the maximum price. This is especially not desirable when the user has just set a minimum price as it has the effect of hiding any products at the top of the range too.

To attempt to resolve this, I changed the range label value returned by Magento by overriding the `_renderRangeLabel()` function in `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price.php` - but this still actually filters with the maximum value subtracted by 0.01.

I have tried to identify where this value is subtracted for the search, but have been unable to identify it. Does anyone know the best way to resolve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific issue of 3d party extension. Similar extensions do not have such rounding bug.

Comment: I would argue this isn't an issue with this specific extension however - I am asking about changing behaviour which is core Magento (it is Magento that alters the price filter breaks in the way described in my question). Consider reopening?